# Inserting multiple values in one column to excel

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

How to insert in excel column all return values in for loop using xlsxwriter library?, because right now here is my outputs in my script loop:

```
Value       :     4.0

Value       :    17.2

Value       :     7.0
```

Result from excel column is just -->>> 'Vaue : 7.0'

Here is my code:

```
for line, file in enumerate(PM2Line):       
    if POA in file: 
       count = count + 1          
       #print file                  
       worksheet.write('B2', file)#---here is my issue..
```

I need to insert them all in one column, but right now it just only updating which is last return value.

Comment: Please refer "bench_excel_writers. py"  file.

Comment: You need to change the row number as you loop through the data. Currently you are writing everything to cell B2.

Answer (score 1):

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
PM2Line = ["Value: 4.0",
           "Value: 17.2",
           "Value: 7.0"]
row = 0
col = 0

for item in PM2Line:
    worksheet.write(row, col, item)
    row += 1
workbook.close()
```

Comment: yup, I already had this, but my point is, I have so many output line by line. so there is a list in every line and right now im just getting the first line and the rest is not getting.

Answer (score 0):

You may concatenate all you files (assuming they are string in my example) and then add it to the column:

```
files = ""
count = 0
for line, file in enumerate(PM2Line):       
    if POA in file: 
       count = count + 1
       files = files + file + "\n"
       #print file                  
if count > 0:
    worksheet.write('B2', files)
```